# PHPUnit + Laravel 5.2 + Attribute not returning properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

User.php - pretty vanilla hasMany relationship:

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
}
```

UserTest.php:

```
public function testTransactionsAttribute()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Verify logged in user is expected user.
    $this->assertTrue($user->username == 'something');

    // Pay something.
    $transaction = $user->payMembershipFee();

    // Verify transaction is in database
    $this->seeInDatabase('transactions', ['amount' => 50, 'user_id' => $user->id]);

    // Verify transaction belongsTo relationship
    $this->assertTrue($transaction->user->username == 'something');

    // Verify user hasMany relationship - fails
    $this->assertTrue($user->transactions->count() > 0, 'The user should have at least one transaction associated.');
}
```

Here's where it gets interesting (I did not modify the database tables - just left PHPUnit and switched to Tinker):

```
$ php artisan tinker
```

Grab user (verified is same user created from test):

```
$user = App\User::first()
```

Copy/Paste assertion:

```
$user->transactions->count()
=> 1
```

Also, when I manually go through the steps locally - it works. So, it appears Laravel 5.2 is acting as expected. However, PHPUnit is not.

I'm wondering if it's possible I'm missing something in the way Laravel 5.2 and PHPUnit work with one another?

Comment: What happens if you place **$user = $user->fresh();** just before the last assertion? I suspect the transaction might not be synced unless a fresh instance is fetched.

Comment: Thanks @macghriogair that got me going down the correct path. Much obliged. If you want the credit, I'll be more than happy to give it to you - just post an answer similar to one I wrote - expanding on your comment. Thanks again - lifesaver.

Comment: Nevermind, happy I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From outside the model (in the test itself, for example):

```
$user = $user->fresh();
```

From inside the model one cannot do something like:

```
$this = $this->fresh();
```

So, inside the method that creates the Transaction for the User:

```
public function createTransaction()
{
    $transaction = new Transaction;
    ...
    $transaction->save();

    // Refresh the relationship specifically        
    $this->load('transactions');

    // There is also fresh([])
    // which is supposed to be able to accept multiple relationships

    return $transaction;
}
```

---

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/refresh-a-model